# python static overloading of member function

Tags: python, oop

I'm new to python and have a simple question: Is it possible to statically overload a member fuction? Like for example so:

```
class A:
    text=""
    def __init__(self, text):
        self.text = text

    def print(self):
        print (self.text)

    @staticmethod
    def print():
        print ("static")

a = A("test") 
a.print()
```

In this case "static" is printed out. Is it impossible to call the member function if a static function with the same name exists? And if not, who do I call it?

Comment: Please update your question to fix the indenting. Python is very sensitive to indenting, as are python programmers.

Comment: My guess is that having a second `print` method defined simply overwrites the first.

Comment: `staticmethod` in Python just means that it doesn't receive any implicit `self` or `cls` argument and can thus be called regardless of class or instance context. That's different from `classmethod`s, which receive a `cls` object. That may be different terminology from other languages…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't overloading the method; you are *replacing* it with the static method. You'll have to pick a different name for the static method.

Comment: @DavidLeeuwestein If you found the answer helpful and it has fully answered your question, you would usually mark this answer as accepted, both for future reference for people with the same problem and as a thank you to the person who answered.

Answer (score 2):

There is no function overloading in python, but you can simulate an overloaded function with the use of a default value:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, text):
        self.text = text

    def print(self=None):
        if self is None:
            print('static')
        else:
            print(self.text)
```

---

```
a = A("test") 
a.print()  # prints "test"
A.print()  # prints "static"
```

Answer (score 1):

Put simply, there is no function overloading in Python in the sense of having two identically-named functions in the same scope.

Each subsequent definition effectively replaces all identically-named definitions before it.

This applies irrespectively of whether any of them are static.